# Is it possible to check the RadioButton and make the item from Hidden to Visible in the runtime code?

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button, border

XAML

```
<Window x:Name="Social_Club" x:Class="SocialClub.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GameMenu"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        MouseDown="Window_MouseDown"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Background="Transparent"
        Title="Game Menu" Height="450" Width="800" Icon="faviconSC.png">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="30">
        <Grid>
            <Border Background="#31313e" CornerRadius="30" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Border Margin="8,6,138,4">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="faviconSC.png"/>
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <TextBlock Text="Social Club" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="22" Margin="0,24,-22,24" FontFamily="Arial Black" Width="160" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>
            </Grid>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                <RadioButton 
                    x:Name="gta6_btn"
                    Content="Grand Theft Auto VI" 
                    Foreground="#fff"
                    Height="70"
                    FontSize="18"
                    FontWeight="ExtraBold"
                    Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                    />

                <RadioButton 
                    x:Name="rdr2_btn"
                    Content="Red Dead Redemption 2" 
                    Foreground="#fff"
                    Height="70"
                    FontSize="16"
                    FontWeight="ExtraBold"
                    Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                    />

                <RadioButton 
                    Content="Grand Theft Auto VI" 
                    Foreground="#fff"
                    Height="70"
                    FontSize="18"
                    FontWeight="ExtraBold"
                    Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                    />

                <RadioButton 
                    Content="Grand Theft Auto VI" 
                    Foreground="#fff"
                    Height="70"
                    FontSize="18"
                    FontWeight="ExtraBold"
                    Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                    />

                <RadioButton 
                    Content="Grand Theft Auto VI" 
                    Foreground="#fff"
                    Height="70"
                    FontSize="18"
                    FontWeight="ExtraBold"
                    Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <Border x:Name="gta6" Visibility="Hidden" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="Rockstar games" Foreground="#FF636363" Margin="10,10,464,337" FontSize="15"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,35,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       Text="Grand Theft Auto VI" Foreground="#FFF" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                       Height="30" Width="199" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20"/>
                    <Border CornerRadius="10" Margin="227,10,10,171">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="prewiew.png"/>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <Border Visibility="Hidden" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></Border>
            <Border Visibility="Hidden" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></Border>
            <Border Visibility="Hidden" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></Border>
            <Border Visibility="Hidden" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></Border>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="208*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="587*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="37*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="186*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

XAML.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SocialClub
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private void Application_Exit(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
                this.DragMove();
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void activeMenu()
        {
            if(gta6_btn.IsChecked == true)
            {
                gta6.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make an application on the type of Launcher, I'm not asking in this thread to help me with the future of the code and help me only with this problem.
The essence of the problem I want to make it so that when RadioButton Border is selected, it goes from Hidden to Visible.
I apologize for my English, and I have very little understanding of C# wpf since I am just starting out.

I tried to do it through the check, but the Border just did not do Visible

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by adding an event handler

```
private void gta6_btn_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        gta6.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```